# Tkinter , root update

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Why i am getting this error with `root.update()` when i destroy the window:

```
_tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".!label"
```

or

```
_tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".!frame.!text"
```

here is an example code:

```
from tkinter import *
import random
r=Tk()
a=Label(r)
b=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
while(True):
    a.configure(text=f'{random.choice(b)}')
    a.pack()
    r.update()
r.mainloop()
```

any way to fix this error?

Comment: For now its fine, but using a `while` loop will cause the window to be unresponsive eventually while dragging window or resizing it, consider using `after()`.

Comment: Anyway, the error here i believe is because, the `while` loop never ends but the `mainloop()` ends and the labels are getting destroyed when the `mainloop()` ends, but still `while` loop is still running with labels,which are destroyed when `mainloop()` ends, so hence the error that the `.!label` is not found

Comment: good explanation, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is because you are running an infinite loop
After closing the window also loop is try to run the program and try to access the Tk() window, but it has been  destroyed.

the solution is break the loop also when you close the window

```
    try:
       a.configure(text=f'{random.choice(b)}')
       r.update()
    except:
        break
```

In above code program will try to access the window, if success it will run the program
Otherwise failed it will execute 'except' condition and break the loop

your full code will be

```
from tkinter import *
import random
r=Tk()
a=Label(r)
a.pack()
b=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
while(True):
    try:
       a.configure(text=f'{random.choice(b)}')
       r.update()
    except:
        break
r.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

That, or similar, happens any time you close a tkinter window and there is an uncompleted action waiting to process.  Frankly, it can be ignored...

..but, if you really want to get rid of it, you need to manage your ongoing processes and wait for them to finish when closing.  You will need to overwrite the destroy() method in a customized version of the Tk class to have that, and you will probably be better off using after() if you want active processes going on with the program.  The way you are doing it right now, it never hits the mainloop so some functionality will not work.

Here is a simple fix:

```
from tkinter import *
import random

class Globals:
    stop = False

class MyTk(Tk):
    def trueDestroy(self):
        Tk.destroy(self)
    def destroy(self):
        Globals.stop = (self)

def myUpdate():
    a.configure(text=f'{random.choice(b)}')
    if Globals.stop:
        r.trueDestroy()
    else:
        r.after(1, myUpdate)

r=MyTk()
a=Label(r)
a.pack()
b=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
r.after(1, myUpdate)
r.mainloop()
```

Really, you should make a queue for each process you have running instead of just one 'stop' function, and then only destroy it once they all are stopped, but hopefully you can extrapolate form this.